# Customize ecto migration primary key and autogenerate

Tags: database, postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to create a users table with an `aid` which is autogenerated and an id which I handle myself.

I have attempted the following migration and schema:

Migration:

```
def change do
  create table(:users, primary_key: false) do
    add :aid, :id, autogenerate: true
    add :id, :integer
    add :first_name, :string
    add :last_name, :string
    add :email, :string
    add :phone, :string
    add :language, :string
    add :password_hash, :string
    add :verified_email, :utc_datetime
    add :verified_phone, :utc_datetime

    timestamps()
  end
```

What is happening when I run this migration is that the `aid` column is not being added into my `user` table

How can I get this to change the database as I would like?

Comment: I have just tried it locally and it did include the aid column, except it wasn't a primary key. I believe you should use `primary_key: true` instead of `autogenerate: true`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @JoséValim, I achieved the desired functionality with: `add :aid, :bigserial, primary_key: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `primary_key: true` instead of `autogenerate: true`:

```
add :aid, :id, primary_key: true
```